# error: input is self closing and should not have content

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I'm trying to pick up some `Jade` to use with express, and I'm having trouble understanding why I'm getting this error. The whole of my .jade file is:

```
.login
#register
  div(style='float:right')
    p
      input.loginInput (type='text', name='user')
    p
      input.loginInput (type='password', name='pass')
    p
      input#button.loginInput (type='submit', value='Join')
  div(style='text-align:right;padding-right:110px;padding-top:3px;')
    p IGN:
    p Password:
  a(href='#' onclick='getProfileLogin()') < Back
```

I'm getting the above error, somehow linked to the inputs (it doesn't happen when I remove them) at `line 13: a(href='#' onclick='getProfileLogin()') < Back`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error message is a little confusing, but the issue is your whitespace before the `(`.

```
input.loginInput (type='text', name='user')
```

should be

```
input.loginInput(type='text', name='user')
```

This also applies to your other input lines.

By having the space, you are declaring an `<input>` with no attributes, and the content `(type='text', name='user')` which is not aloud because the HTML spec defined `<input>` tags as `Empty`, meaning then can have no child nodes.

Comment: Nice .. it's a subtle detail to be aware of, considering many languages ignore extra white space.  Thanks for clearing this up!